# Set a range limit for the date parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report where I defined two parameters to set the `starting date` and `ending date`.

However, I want to implement a logic so that the user can choose `starting date` and `ending date` unless the range between them pass over 1 year. As an example, if the user chooses **"01/01/2017"** for the start date, the maximum available end date must be displayed and limited to **"01/01/2018"**. The vice versa also must be applied, when the user chooses the end date first, start date must be limited.

Is that possible to implement this logic into Sql Reporting Services? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does this question has to do with `sql-server` ?

Comment: This answer may help: [Report Parameter validation in ssrs report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30478957/1048425)

Comment: You *can* , however, you won't be able to use the calendar picker any more and would have to make it so that the user has a drop down list of all the relevant dates. You would be better off presenting an "error" if they select a too large date range.